# Failed to Install Local Notification in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, installation, local

If I installed ionic "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification" in Ionic I get an error.

"Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-local-notification': CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"

"Error: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed. You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads. Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4" could someone help me?

Comment: Try with changing the 'target' property on file project.properties to 'android-26'.  (/platforms/android/project.properties) or if you are using cordova 7  then Try use the --nofetch  and use this command ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification --nofetch

Comment: I found a solution by changing the JAVA_HOME and PATH, Thanks for replying.